# Image Grid Fluid Layout (Responsive)

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I am working on image grid(4 columns) with fluid layout. In jsfiddle currently the height is set to auto but it's not coming the way I am expecting because the image dimensions are different. The image size is not proportional after fixing the height. I know, it will work properly when image(width/height) will be equal but I don't want to do this because images will be coming dynamically(same width/different height). Is there any way it can be fixed for different image dimensions? Fiddle below

```
img{
  width:100%;
  //height:150px;
  height:auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wFLJW)

Answer (score 2):

I took a different approach. You said that the widths will remain the same, whereas the heights will vary. As opposed to floating each individual img, I think it's better (and easier) to place the imgs within a column, and float the columns, rather.

[**Live demo, try resizing the browser and stuff...**](http://jsfiddle.net/uEyCF/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="image_box">


<div class="col">
<img><img><img><img><img><img>
</div>


<div class="col">
<img><img><img><img><img><img>
</div>


<div class="col">
<img><img><img><img><img><img>
</div>


<div class="col">
<img><img><img><img><img><img>
</div>


<div class="col">
<img><img><img><img><img><img>
</div>


</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#image_box {
   width:90%;
   margin:0px auto;
}

.col {
   width:18%;
   float:left;
   margin:0px 1%;
}
img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  margin-top:6%;
}
```

I just threw this together relatively quickly.. if you wanted to improve the layout, you could specify a different width for `.image_box`, and have columns overflow under the other columns.

Comment: Note: Avast antivurs goes nuts on the live demo link

Comment: Thank you for the effort. but I dont want to put into seperate divs. the mark up will remain same, as i said its fluid layout, and image thumbs are supposed to display there with equal width and height, doesn't matter the screen size. In your code the images are not coming equal.

Comment: Yes. Equal width and height and stick with each other

Comment: @JoshC is was not your website but the image links apparently http://i.imgur.com/utUpgsS.png

Answer (score 0):

One option is to restrict the height of the img container. In your case, the li elements.

```
li {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You would have to provide a height that would work with the smallest possible image size.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried a few changes in your css,

please find below jsfiddle

```
'http://jsfiddle.net/wFLJW/3/'
```